# Switch toggle changes style after form submit

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Added a switch toggle to form to filter products. [That one](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp). After form submit, page reloading through ajax and switch is changing it's style again before toggle. Why is that happening and what I can do to fix it? By the way, if I click on switch toggle and refresh a whole page there is no problem with switch toggle.Thanks for any advice.

[image]

Comment: Can you copy us your javascript code? It seems like if you are replacing the switch with the response code

Comment: JS: 
    $(document).on('click', '.storehouse_switch', function () {
    form_search(true);
});
It just submitting form after click switch.

Answer (score 0):

That's because, after submitting form, the DOM is replaced by the new one, so the old checkbox is removed. You should bind your checkbox with this switch toggle script again for the new DOM.